# Regex to find integers in brackets

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to find integers within the bracket in a string using python's regex. The rule is there can be whitespace between the number and the brackets, but no other character besides those that make up the integer. Here is my code:

```
import re
a = "  afd [asd] [12 ] [a34]  [ -43 ]tt [+12]xxx"
b = "  afd [asd] [12 ] [a34]  [       -43 ]tt [+12]xxx!"
c = "  afd [128+] [47 ] [a34]  [ +-43 ]tt [+12]xxx"
from_a = re.findall(r'\[[\s+]*(-?\d+)\s*\]',a)
from_b = re.findall(r'\[[\s+]*(-?\d+)\s*\]',b)
from_c = re.findall(r'\[[\s+]*(-?\d+)\s*\]',c)
```

This particular regex works for strings a and b and give the required output. However, in string c when there comes two (+ or -) signs after either bracket '[' or whitespace, regex should ignore that integer.

EDIT

```
expected results
from_a = [12,-43,12]
from_b = [12,-43,12]
from_c = [47,12]
```

Comment: Why should it be ignored? The `+` is matched by `[\s+]*`, and the `-` is matched by `-?`

Comment: If you want to allow optional `+` or `-` but not both, use `[-+]?\d+`

Comment: there can be only single + or - sign at a time. if there are two, then the integers needs to be ignored

Comment: Do you mean you want `\[\s*(-?\d+)\s*]`? Or `\[\s*([-+]?\d+)\s*]` ? You should have indicated expected results.

Comment: I hope my answer helped.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
\[\s*(?:\+(?=\d))?(-?\d+)\s*]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a6uYX8/1).

**Details**

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:\+(?=\d))?` - an optional `+` that must be followed with a digit
- `(-?\d+)` - Group 1: an optional `-` and then 1+ digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `]` - a `]` char.

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/IZHJvT):

```
import re
strs = ['  afd [asd] [12 ] [a34]  [ -43 ]tt [+12]xxx','  afd [asd] [12 ] [a34]  [       -43 ]tt [+12]xxx!','  afd [128+] [47 ] [a34]  [ +-43 ]tt [+12]xxx']
for s in strs:
    print( re.findall(r'\[\s*(?:\+(?=\d))?(-?\d+)\s*]', s) )
```

Output:

```
['12', '-43', '12']
['12', '-43', '12']
['47', '12']
```

Answer (score 0):

`+` should not be in the brackets with `\s`. That allows any number of `+` characters before the number, which can optionally begin with `-`.

Use `[-+]?` to allow an optional sign at the beginning of the number.

```
from_c = re.findall(r'\[\s*([-+]?\d+)\s*\]',c)
print(from_c)
['47', '+12']
```